# Two Headed Giant - do I gain life when my teammate gains life?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-multiplayer, mtg-two-headed-giant

I'm playing Two-Headed Giant. I have [Ajani's Pridemate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383181), which has "Whenever you gain life...".
My teammate plays a card, that makes him gain life. As we share our life total, my life is also updated. Do I get to activate Pridemate's ability, when my teammate plays the card?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the Pridemate's ability doesn't trigger when your teammate gains life, because while your shared life total goes up it is not you gaining life.

[Two-Headed Giant FAQ](https://wpn.wizards.com/sites/wpn/files/attachements/magic_the_gathering_twoheaded_giant_tournament_faq_pdf1.pdf):

> **How does damage, loss of life, and gaining life work with the single life total for the team?**
>   Damage, loss of life, and gaining life happens to each player individually. The result is applied to the
>   team’s shared life total.

Comment: 810.9 in the [comprehensive rules](http://media.wizards.com/2016/docs/MagicCompRules_04082016.pdf) also states this.

Comment: You'd think the inverse would also be true, but Platinum Emperion is a funny card.

Comment: @HaoYe No, Platinum Emperion doesn't say you can't gain or lose life, it says your life total cannot change, your team mate gaining or losing life would change your life total, so since that can't happen, they can't gain or lose life either. If platinum Emperion had been worded to say you can't gain or lose life, then your ally could still cause your shared life total to change by gaining or losing life.

Comment: @Andrew, as rule says, if you can't gain life, your teammate can't gain life either. 810.9g If an effect says that a player can’t gain life, no player on that player’s team can gain life.